# Requiring an object from another file currently strips out Regex key values

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, webpack, requirejs

I'm currently iterating over a few different directories, requiring Webpack Configuration objects from these different directories, and starting a child process in node that runs the webpack compiler with that given configuration object.

When I use require( webpackConfigPath ), it strips out the regex values for `module: { rules : [ { test: /\.js$/, ...} ]}`, and replaces them with an empty object, bringing over something that looks like this: `module: { rules : [ { test: {}, ...} ]}`

Can anybody provide me direction on how to deep clone a variable from another file without these RegExp key values being stripped out and replaced with empty objects?

Example in usage:

```
const webpackConfigDir = path.resolve( __dirname, themeDir + '/webpack.config.js' )
let config = require( webpackConfigDir );
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by requiring a constructor function for the webpack configuration instead.

Example:

`webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require("path");

const entryPath = path.resolve( __dirname, 'source/scripts/app.js' );
const outputPath = path.resolve( __dirname, 'dist/js' )

const constructConfig = function ( entryPath, outputPath )  {
    const config = {
        entry: ["@babel/polyfill", entryPath],
        output: {
            path: outputPath,
            filename: "scripts.js"
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    use: "babel-loader",
                    exclude: /node_modules/
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [],
        devtool: 'source-map',
        externals: {
            jquery: 'jQuery'
        }
    }
    return config
}

module.exports = {
    constructor: constructConfig,
    entry: entryPath,
    output: outputPath
}
```

I then converted the constructor function to a string, since node child processes don't allow functions to be passed in, only objects, as far as I could tell.

`scripts.js`:

```
    let configConstructor = require( webpackConfigDir ).constructor
    let entry = require( webpackConfigDir ).entry
    let output = require( webpackConfigDir ).output

    let processOptions = {
        constructor: configConstructor.toString(),
        entry: entry,
        output: output
    }

    process.send( processOptions )
```

Within the child process being ran, I converted the string back into a function that gets called once returned.

`build.js`:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const chalk = require('chalk');

async function build(config) {
    await webpack( config, (err, stats) => {
        if ( stats.hasErrors() ) {
            const errors = stats.toJson().errors

            errors.forEach( (error, i) => {
                console.log( chalk.white.bgRed.bold(`Error #${i + 1}: `) + chalk.white.bgRed(`${error}`) )
            })
        }
    })
}

process.on("message", async options => {
    const constructor = new Function( 'return ' + options.constructor )();
    const config = await constructor( options.entry, options.output )
    await build(config);
});
```

This solution worked for the problem at hand, figured I would share in the event anybody runs into a similar problem. In this case, I was trying to share project dependencies but allow a different webpack configuration on a per-directory basis.